# Use powershell to add text to a .conf file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I tried add-content command to add the following lines to a .conf file but didn't work, I think the reason it didnt work is because the file is not a .txt file, it is a .conf file.

```
[sslConfig]

sslVersions = *,-ssl2,-ssl3

cipherSuite = TLSv1.2:!eNULL:!aNULL

allowSslRenegotiation = false
```

Is there a way of adding additional lines to the end of a .conf file using powershell?

Comment: Which type of .conf are you talking about. You discribe a kind of .ini file.

Answer (score 1):

```
"new line content" | out-file .\ssl.conf -append -encoding ascii
```